# How to connect more than 1 device using tcp connection with ADB over wifi

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop

I have 5 devices.No one is rooted. I want to connect 2 devices using USB and 3 using tcp over wifi with ADB at same time. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can connect multiple devices via USB. You just need to specify that device when you connect with adb by calling commands like this

```
> adb -s _device_serial_number_ [adb-command]
```

you can also connect multiple devices over wifi by using the following command

```
> adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555
```

this is the IP address and Port of the device that ADB is listening on. Now you setup your connections on your PC.

```
> adb connect 192.168.1.51:5555
> adb connect 192.168.1.52:5555
> adb connect 192.168.1.53:5555
```

check if they are all connected.

```
> adb devices
> 192.168.1.51:5555 device
> 192.168.1.52:5555 device
> 192.168.1.53:5555 device
> _device1_serial device
> _device2_serial device
```